# Writing an R package containing C++ code in Eclipse/StatET

Tags: c++, eclipse, r, statet

I'm trying to figure out how to set up Eclipse so that I can write R projects and packages which contain C++ code also.

Of course I could make separate R and C++ projects, compile the C++ code, copy the .dll to R project and use it in R using dyn.load function, but what If I want to build an R package which contains C++ source codes? I could again have separate C++ and R projects, put copy the C++ codes into the src folder of my R package, and I guess using R package builder within StatET perspective would work properly? But I'm wondering can I make just one R package project and embed C++ code inside of that project so that I get the benefits of the C++ perspective, ie. color codings of the code etc?

I know someone will mention Rcpp, but that is not an option here. I'm trying to learn C++ and how to combine it with R in a hard way first.

I'm using both Linux and Windows.

edit: Just to clarify, I want to know how I can set up Eclipse so that it understands both R and C++ codes at the same time, ie. both codes have color codings etc.

Comment: Why Rcpp is not an option? RStudio has nice R/C++ integration with Rcpp http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/using_rcpp

Comment: I already use Eclipse for my Fortran programs and I'd like to use same IDE for all my programming tasks.

Comment: ok, so I understand the only one is StatET. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am as much as fan of the editor war's as anybody else but you misunderstand.  Take what you wrote:

> I'm trying to learn C++ and how to combine it with R in a hard way
>   first.

So read "Writing R Extensions" carefully, and redo the examples.  On the command-line. Then learn how to use a Makefile.

It is about the *code* and the *compiler invocation*.  Whether you write the code in vi, Emacs, or Eclipse does not matter if you do not understand how to call the compiler, or how to write your code.  So your intent is right: learn these basics.

Once you grok all that plumming you are ready to insert appropriate declarations into your Eclipse/StatET configurations.

(And if you want to cheat I could point you to the contributed cmake files in the RInside package.)

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have written more carefully or left the whole Rcpp part away as that wasn't really the point here. The reason I am not currently interested in Rcpp is that we are going to have a seminar about statistical programming in C++ and R, and we wish to follow a certain material for this (which does not cover Rcpp). Most of the participants do not know anything about C++, so part of the course is to learn C++, and other part is to learn how to incorporate these C++ codes in R or other way around.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, Rcpp makes this easier, but I feel it is useful to know how to do this in classical way first. Later on the course if we have time, we can examine the Rcpp, and they will then they will appriciate the Rcpp more. ;)

Comment: So my question is really just about how can I use Eclipse so that it understands both R and C++ code at the same time. Eclipse because that is what most of the participants of the seminar already use when writing pure R.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems that I had poorly installed Eclipse which caused some problems. The answer to my question is that I can work in StatET perspective and it automatically understands C++ code if the filename extension is of form .c or .cpp. I can then compile the code by using R CMD SHLIB or R CMD INSTALL, if the code is part of some package.